# How to correctly place .addClass and .removeClass in Modal Box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The problem is that I have been made aware that I should stop using `.hide` and `.show` within my javascript. Now I have learned that a better alternative is to use `.addClass` and `.removeClass` as this provides better control and more stylizing.

However for some reason the code is not working. Could I please get help?

I have replaced the previous `.hide` and `.show` with the new `.addClass` and `.removeClass`, I have provided a new class named showme and even css to display the code as a block.

```js
var content = "";
$('a[href="#ex5"]').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).modal({
    escapeClose: false,
    clickClose: false,
    showClose: false,
  });
  $('#myDiv, #myDivs').hide();
  $('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false);
});

$('.yourCheckbox, .yourCheckboxx').change(function() {
  if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
    $("#" + $(this).data('target')).addClass('showme');
    content = $("#" + $(this).data('target')).html();
  } else {
    $("#" + $(this).data('target')).removeClass('showme');
    content = "";
  }
});


$('[rel="modal:close"]').on('click', () => {
  $('.btn').parent().append(content);
})
```

```css
.onlyThese {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"]+label {
  color: blue
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label {
  color: red
}


}
input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.showme {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- Remember to include jQuery :) -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery Modal -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />

<p>
  <a class="btn" href="#ex5">Sectors </a>
</p>
<div id="ex5" ; class="modal" ; style="background-color:white">
  <div style="float:left;">
    <p>
      <input type="checkbox" id="group1" class="yourCheckbox" data-target="myDiv" checked="checked">
      <label for="group1" class="onlyThese">Publication </label>
    </p>
    <div id="myDiv" class="showme"> blastoise </div>
    <p>
      <input type="checkbox" id="group2" class="yourCheckboxx" data-target="myDivs" checked="checked">
      <label for="group2" class="onlyThese">Food </label>
    </p>
    <div id="myDivs" class="showme"> water </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <p style="float:right">
        <a href="#" rel="modal:close" ; class="onlyThese;"> <b>Apply</b> </a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

All I want is for the code to work the way it used to with `.hide` and `.show` but instead now using `.addClass` and `.removeClass`.

Comment: Just FYI you don't need to append 4 spaces to the lines containing the snippet logic. This is about the 5th question of yours where I've had to edit that to make the snippet work.

Comment: How can I correctly space the snippets? I am indenting as told to?

Comment: Also note that you're including 3 different versions of jQuery, remove 1.9.1 and 3.0.0, and also some of your HTML elements have random `;` in them which should also be removed.

Comment: `How can I correctly space the snippets?` You don't need to. Just hit 'Save & Insert' button and submit the question.

Comment: Will do for future questions, thanks kind sir.

Comment: I am using php Magnus Eriksson.

Comment: That may well be the case, but PHP is not at all relevant to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to remove and add class in different conditions or you could use `toggleClass` using `.hideme` class instead of `.showme`:

```js
var content = "";
$('a[href="#ex5"]').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).modal({
    escapeClose: false,
    clickClose: false,
    showClose: false,
  });
  $('#myDiv, #myDivs').addClass('hideme');
  $('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false);
});

$('.yourCheckbox, .yourCheckboxx').change(function() {
  if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
    //$("#" + $(this).data('target')).removeClass('hideme');
    content = $("#" + $(this).data('target')).html();
  } else {
    //$("#" + $(this).data('target')).addClass('hideme');
    content = "";
  }

  $("#" + $(this).data('target')).toggleClass('hideme');
});


$('[rel="modal:close"]').on('click', () => {
  $('.btn').parent().append(content);
})
```

```css
.onlyThese {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"]+label {
  color: blue
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label {
  color: red
}


}
input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.hideme {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- Remember to include jQuery :) -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery Modal -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />

<p>
  <a class="btn" href="#ex5">Sectors </a>
</p>
<div id="ex5" ; class="modal" ; style="background-color:white">
  <div style="float:left;">
    <p>
      <input type="checkbox" id="group1" class="yourCheckbox" data-target="myDiv" checked="checked">
      <label for="group1" class="onlyThese">Publication </label>
    </p>
    <div id="myDiv" class="showme"> blastoise </div>
    <p>
      <input type="checkbox" id="group2" class="yourCheckboxx" data-target="myDivs" checked="checked">
      <label for="group2" class="onlyThese">Food </label>
    </p>
    <div id="myDivs" class="showme"> water </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <p style="float:right">
        <a href="#" rel="modal:close" ; class="onlyThese;"> <b>Apply</b> </a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```